# Using Html.NameFor on ICollections

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework

I've got an Entity Framework Model (Course), it contains a collection of (Student) entities.

I use AngularJS on the front-end and pass the Course entity to my view.

From the View, I need to use Html.NameFor() to create unique names for each property of the Model so it can map back to a Model when passed to an API.

```
// Course Model
class Course {
    ICollection<Student> Students;
}

// Student Model
class Student {
    public string FullName {get; set;}
}

// MyView.vbhtml
@ModelType Course
<input type = 'text' name = '@Html.NameFor(Function (Model) Model.Students(0).FullName)'/>
```

I would expect the name of the input field to be 'Students(0).FullName'.

but it's coming out just as 'FullName'.

Is there anyway I can get the desired results ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on wether you're trying to get it to be Students(0).Fullname as a literal string or the actual name of the student in the collection but either way you'd have to loop it

```
for(int i =0; i < Students.Count; i++)
{
<input type='text' name=Students(i).FullName
}
```

Would give you it as a literal string i.e Students(1).FullName or Students(2).FullName

```
for(int i =0; i < Students.Count; i++)
{
<input type='text' name=Students[i].FullName
}
```

Would give you it as their actual name (note the [] instead of ())